# Java swing button action not working?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, actionlistener

So to start off, I am building a program for my girlfriend for her birthday in 2 days. The problem I am having right now is that my button within my GUI is not working. When someone clicks the button, it is supposed to show the pic that I set it to that is a jpg inside of the program files. Instead it just does nothing. I was wondering if I could get some help as to why the button may not be functioning? It is within the Happy_birthday() constructor. Thank you very much for your time. Note: There are some inside jokes and comments throughout the program sorry if they seem bothersome just trying to make her laugh is all.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Happy_birthday extends JFrame{
public Happy_birthday(){
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p5 = new JPanel();
    JLabel word1 = new JLabel("You might want to take a photo to remember the dates.");
    JLabel word2 = new JLabel(" The format goes from year, to month, to day");
    JLabel word3 = new JLabel("|2014 1 22|");
    JLabel word4 = new JLabel("|2015 7 28|");
    JLabel word5 = new JLabel("|2014 1 10|");
    JLabel word6 = new JLabel("|2016 1 22|");
    JLabel word7 = new JLabel("|2015 9 1|");
    p1.add(word1);
    p1.add(word2);
    p1.add(word3);
    p1.add(word4);
    p1.add(word5);
    p1.add(word6);
    p1.add(word7);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Option 1 for favorite pic.");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("CassyPic.jpg");
            p2.add(new JLabel(icon));
        }
    });
    p2.add(button1);
    add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p2,BorderLayout.EAST);
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("---   ---       ---     ----------   ----------  --    --");
    System.out.println("---   ---      -- --    ---     ---  ---     ---  --  --");
    System.out.println("---------     --- ---   ---    ---   ---    ---    ----");
    System.out.println("---------    ---------  ---------    ---------      --");
    System.out.println("---   ---   --      --  ---          ---            --");
    System.out.println("---   ---  --        -- ---          ---            --" );
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("---------      ----     ----------   ---------- ---   ---");
    System.out.println("----------      --      ---    ---      ----    ---   ---");
    System.out.println("---   ---       --      ---   ---       ----    ---------");
    System.out.println("--------        --      --------        ----    ---------");
    System.out.println("---   ---       --      ---  ---        ----    ---   ---");
    System.out.println("----------      --      ---   ---       ----    ---   ---");
    System.out.println("---------      ----     ---    ---      ----    ---   ---");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("--------       ---    --    --");
    System.out.println("---------     -- --    --  --" );
    System.out.println("---   ---    --- ---    ----");
    System.out.println("---   ---   ---------    --");
    System.out.println("---  --    ---     ---   --");
    System.out.println("------    ---       ---  --");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("OK, now since that is out of the way time to begin with the real fun :)");
    System.out.println("So first off a joke, what is a fish that has no eyes?");
    System.out.println("Find out the answer later. For now type in dates that you think are relevant to our relationship");
    String word="";
    System.out.println("For some hints, type in the word 'hint' to get some help");
    word = input.nextLine();
    if(word.equals("hint")){
        Happy_birthday TuSa = new Happy_birthday();
        TuSa.setTitle("Help window");
        TuSa.setSize(200,130);
        TuSa.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        TuSa.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TuSa.setVisible(true);
    }
    int choiceCount=0;
    int day = 0, year = 0, month = 0;
    while(choiceCount<5){
        boolean dayFlag = true;
        boolean monthFlag = true;
        boolean yearFlag = true;
        while(dayFlag){
            System.out.print("Type in a day: ");
            day = input.nextInt();
            if(day>31 || day<0){
                System.out.println("That isn't a legitimate day. Try again");
                dayFlag = true;
            }
            else{
                dayFlag = false;
            }
        }
        while(monthFlag){
            System.out.print("Type in a number for the month: ");
            month = input.nextInt();
            if(month<0 || month>12){
                System.out.println("That isn't a legitimate month. Try again");
                monthFlag = true;
            }
            else{
                monthFlag = false;
            }
        }
        while(yearFlag){
            System.out.print("Type in the year(4 digits): ");
            year = input.nextInt();
            if(year<2014 && year>1995){
                System.out.println("We were not even dating by this point. Try again.");
                yearFlag = true;
            }
            else if(year<=1995){
                System.out.println("You were not even born so chill out lol.");
                yearFlag = true;
                //TU SA TU SA IN DUH AIR!
            }
            else if(year>2016){
                System.out.println("That hasn't even happened yet???");
                yearFlag = true;
            }
            else{
                yearFlag = false;
            }
        }
        if(year == 2014 && month == 1 && day == 22){
            System.out.println("The day we started dating. Crazy how it's been almost 3 years :)");
            choiceCount++;
        }
        if(year == 2015 && month == 7 && day == 28){
            System.out.println("The day (or aorund that time) that we went to six flags and had Mt. tom's ice cream :)");
            choiceCount++;
        }
        if(year == 2014 && month == 1 && day == 10){
            System.out.println("Around this time is when you said I love you using Pokemon. I still love that you did that <3");
            choiceCount++;
        }
        if(year == 2016 && month == 1 && day == 22){
            System.out.println("The time we went to Ninja :)");
            choiceCount++;
        }
        if(year == 2015 && month == 9 && day == 1){
            System.out.println("Around this time is when I am hoping Orenda started? And they got the best president possible :)");
            choiceCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Time to move onto somthing a bit different");
    System.out.println("I have compiled a couple of things for you.");
    System.out.println("Type in 1 for a pic that I really like.");
    System.out.println("Type in 2 for a pic from the place that we had our best date");
    System.out.println("Type in 3 for a random corny joke");
    System.out.println("Type in 4 to continue on :)");
    boolean inner_choice = true;
    int inner_switch = 0;
    while(inner_choice){
        switch(inner_switch){
        case(1):

            inner_choice = true;
        case(2):

            inner_choice = true;
        case(3):

            inner_choice = true;
        case(4):
            inner_choice = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). This should only require one button, and a window to display it..

Comment: Solve first by simplification: try to create the most simple program, say one that has just a simple main method that displays an ImageIcon in a JOptionPane (yes you can do this -- pass it in as the second parameter), and try to show your image this way, debugging as you go. Next try to get the image as a class resource, not as a file...

Comment: Only after verifying that you can get and display the image should you try to incorporate it into the main GUI.

Comment: You're adding a new component _after_ `setVisible`; instead, `add()` the component, `pack()` the window and call `setIcon()` in the listener.

Comment: BTW - `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("CassyPic.jpg");
            p2.add(new JLabel(icon));` a label with no text, icon or border is invisible. So add the label at startup and simply set the icon on action..

Comment: Try calling `p2.revalidate();` after `p2.add(new JLabel(...));`

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: As others have pointed out: your problem is that adding something to a panel ... isn't enough for the JPanel to redraw itself and display what has been added. And when you got some more time: A) turn to the help center, and read a bit about how to ask "code not working" questions B) read some java coding style guides ... you dont put _ into class names for example C) read about "Single layer of abstraction" and "single responsibility" principles --- you are doing **way** to many things within your methods; you should have much more smaller methods in stead.

Answer (score -1):

You can try it like this: (change your on action performed code to this code below)

```
try {
    // read the image from the cource
    BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(Happy_birthday.class.getResourceAsStream("/CassyPic.jpg"));
    // create icon
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(read);
    // add icon to the panel (p2)
    p2.add(new JLabel(icon));
    // the most important thing that you must do is this
    p2.revalidate(); // 2. re validate the panel (p2) to take effect.
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: There are better approaches than this. One mentioned in a comment above, the other being a `CardLayout` ..

Comment: The order is revalidate() and then repaint(). You want to invoke the layout manager before repainting all the components.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes you are right, I just solve his problem at the point he want, I did not make the answer complex, may cause he couldn't understand.

Comment: @camickr Yes, that is right. Even not call to repaint() also can do the things which is expected.